# Adding tasks dynamically to airflow DAG using a for loop is causing Exception: DAG is missing the start_date error

Tags: airflow, airflow-2.x

I have a DAG which runs fine as long as I do not use a for loop to dynamically add tasks to it.
As soon as I use a for loop, it starts throwing error.

```
Broken DAG: [/usr/local/airflow/dags/my_dag.py] Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/airflow/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/airflow/models/baseoperator.py", line 1053, in dag
    dag.add_task(self)
  File "/usr/local/airflow/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/airflow/models/dag.py", line 2314, in add_task
    raise AirflowException("DAG is missing the start_date parameter")
airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: DAG is missing the start_date parameter
```

### DAG File

```
default_args = {
    'owner': 'aws',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': datetime(2019, 2, 20),
    'provide_context': True
}


dag = DAG(dag_id='my_dag',
        description='my_datapipeline',
        tags=['k8s'],
        catchup=False,
        schedule_interval='0 0 * * *',
        default_args=default_args
    )

// skipping other tasks

for i in range(num_pods):
    start_idx = i * max_files_per_pod
    end_idx = min(start_idx + max_files_per_pod, len(metric_config))
    file_subset = myconfig[start_idx:end_idx]
    task_id = f'my{i}'
    KubernetesPodOperator(
        task_id=task_id,
        full_pod_spec=full_pod_spec_metric_flow,
        volumes=[volume],
        name=task_id,
        get_logs=True,
        is_delete_operator_pod=False,
        in_cluster=False,
        config_file=kube_config_path,
        startup_timeout_seconds=240,
        cluster_context='aws',
        trigger_rule='all_done',
        arguments=['--json_files',','.join(file_subset)],
        dag=dag)
```

Why this error comes up only when I try to use a for loop to add tasks and how to fix it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are providing the start date to all of your tasks through default_args, but you should be passing it as an argument to your DAG. I don’t think the for loop is the problem.